# Why i can not use arabic character in hello chart library in android studio?

Tags: android

I use the hello chart library in my android project and i want use arabic character in chart,but when write this code:

```
axisX.setName("تجزیه و تحلیل");
```

i can not see a any character in my chart,what happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution for this as i know is to add the values of arabic/hebrew to string value file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <resources> <string name="app_name">בלהבלה</string> <string name="splash_text"> בדיקה? </string> </resources>
```

after adding to the file you can add the value to your text box like this:

```
textBox.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
```

i don't know what library of chart you using, but it sound like encoding problem..

Answer (score -1):

try to write the text to the string value file in the resources, i think is because the text need to be as UTF8...

Comment: How can i write that string resource with UTF8?

Comment: add new file to the values directory and add new xml or use strings.xml, <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">בלהבלה</string>
 <string name="splash_text">
 בדיקה?
 </string>
</resources>